# Guess formula for sequence in FriCAS

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, math-software

How to use package for guessing formulas for sequences in FriCAS? I opened [SandBox](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/SandBoxGuessingSequence?root=SandBox), entered commands

```
\begin{axiom}
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
guessRec(l);
\end{axiom}
```

and clicked "Preview", but received following error message:

> There are 3 exposed and 0 unexposed library operations named 
>         equation having 2 argument(s) but none was determined to be 
>         applicable. Use HyperDoc Browse, or issue
>                               )display op equation
>         to learn more about the available operations. Perhaps 
>         package-calling the operation or using coercions on the arguments
>         will allow you to apply the operation.
>         Cannot find a definition or applicable library operation named 
>         equation with argument type(s) 
>                                    Variable(l)
>                               List(PositiveInteger)
>         Perhaps you should use "@" to indicate the required return type, 
>         or "$" to specify which version of the function you need.

I also downloaded FriCAS for Windows, entered

```
 l := [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
 guessRec(l);
```

but received only message

> Type: List(Expression(Integer))

Comment: I cannot find in OEIS sequence I'm interested in.

Comment: Thank you, this works. You can make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example (FriCAS on Windows), you are somehow suppressing the output of the calculation result and are only seeing its data type instead.

To get around this, you want to either leave out the semicolon, or else follow it with a `%`.